# javascript algorithm converting to roman numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm

The following algorithm is to convert ordinal numbers into Roman numbers. It works for most of numbers, but for some of them still has problems. For example, the numbers 500 or 1000 dont work, and I dont know why. I know I am missing something; any help?

The code is:

```
function convertToRoman(num) {
  //TABLE OF EQUIVALENCES
  var arrConv=[{1:'I'},{2:'II'},{3:'III'},{4:'IV'},{5:'V'},{6:'VI'},{7:'VII'},{8:'VIII'},{9:'IX'},{10:'X'},{20:'XX'},{30:'XXX'},{40:'XL'},{50:'L'},{60:'LX'},{70:'LXX'},{80:'LXXX'},{90:'XC'},{100:'C'},{200:'CC'},{300:'CCC'},{400:'CD'},{500:'D'},{600:'DC'},{700:'DCC'},{800:'DCCC'},{900:'CM'},{1000:'M'},{2000:'MM'},{3000:'MMM'},{4000:'MMMM'},{5000:'MMMMM'},{6000:'MMMMMM'},{7000:'MMMMMMM'},{8000:'MMMMMMMM'},{9000:'MMMMMMMMM'}];

  //First we break down the number into its units
  //and create an array ex: 652 ==> [600, 50, 2]
  var arr=[num.length];
  arr=num.toString().split("").reverse();
  var i=1;
  for (var k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
    arr.splice(k,1,arr[k]*i);
    i*=10;
  }

  //We make an array of objects with the number and the roman number equivalence
 var romansArray=[];
  for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var val=arrConv.filter(function(obj){
       return obj[arr[i]];
     })[0];
    romansArray.push(val);
  }

  //I get rid of all the null values
  var result=romansArray.filter(function(val){
    return (val!=null);
  });

  //It returns the string with the roman number
  return result.map(function(value,key){
    return result[key][arr[key]];
  }).reverse().join("");

}
```

Comment: why not use an conversation object instead of an array and the need of looping, like `{ 1: 'I', 2: 'II', ...}`

Comment: It is true, I agree with you. I think my problem is that I began the algorithm wrongly and I followed it avoiding any change. Thx!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @Nina Scholz answer is the correct (and also, elegant), but note that you have trouble with the zeros (actually, like Romans had!).

If you want your code to work, you have to add the zero to the conversion array, the first think would be just add `{0:''}` but then, as empty string, the filter function will fail, so you can add a space for the key '0', and finally, apply a trim the result.

Something like this:

```
function convertToRoman(num) {
  //TABLE OF EQUIVALENCES
  var arrConv=[{0:' '},{1:'I'},{2:'II'},{3:'III'},{4:'IV'},{5:'V'},{6:'VI'},{7:'VII'},{8:'VIII'},{9:'IX'},{10:'X'},{20:'XX'},{30:'XXX'},{40:'XL'},{50:'L'},{60:'LX'},{70:'LXX'},{80:'LXXX'},{90:'XC'},{100:'C'},{200:'CC'},{300:'CCC'},{400:'CD'},{500:'D'},{600:'DC'},{700:'DCC'},{800:'DCCC'},{900:'CM'},{1000:'M'},{2000:'MM'},{3000:'MMM'},{4000:'MMMM'},{5000:'MMMMM'},{6000:'MMMMMM'},{7000:'MMMMMMM'},{8000:'MMMMMMMM'},{9000:'MMMMMMMMM'}];

  //First we break down the number into its units
  //and create an array ex: 652 ==> [600, 50, 2]
  var arr=[num.length];
  arr=num.toString().split("").reverse();
  var i=1;
  for (var k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
    arr.splice(k,1,arr[k]*i);
    i*=10;
  }

  //We make an array of objects with the number and the roman number equivalence
 var romansArray=[];
  for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var val=arrConv.filter(function(obj){
       return obj[arr[i]];
     })[0];
    romansArray.push(val);
  }

  //I get rid of all the null values
  var result=romansArray.filter(function(val){
    return (val!=null);
  });

  //It returns the string with the roman number
  return result.map(function(value,key){
    return result[key][arr[key]];
  }).reverse().join("").trim();

}
```

Anyway, as I said, the Nina's answer is the good one.

Comment: thank you, silly me!!, i don't know why I didn't think about it before! and I also think @Nina is right!. Thank you both!

Answer (score 3):

You could change a bit

- An object instead of an array of objects.
- The access of the values.
- A default value for not known parts.
- Then you can omit the filtering for `null` values.

```js
function convertToRoman(num) {
    var arrConv = { 1: 'I', 2: 'II', 3: 'III', 4: 'IV', 5: 'V', 6: 'VI', 7: 'VII', 8: 'VIII', 9: 'IX', 10: 'X', 20: 'XX', 30: 'XXX', 40: 'XL', 50: 'L', 60: 'LX', 70: 'LXX', 80: 'LXXX', 90: 'XC', 100: 'C', 200: 'CC', 300: 'CCC', 400: 'CD', 500: 'D', 600: 'DC', 700: 'DCC', 800: 'DCCC', 900: 'CM', 1000: 'M', 2000: 'MM', 3000: 'MMM', 4000: 'MMMM', 5000: 'MMMMM', 6000: 'MMMMMM', 7000: 'MMMMMMM', 8000: 'MMMMMMMM', 9000: 'MMMMMMMMM' };

    var arr = num.toString().split("").reverse(),
        i = 1, k;
    for (k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        arr.splice(k, 1, arr[k] * i);
        i *= 10;
    }

    var romansArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        romansArray.push(arrConv[arr[i]]||'');
    }

    //It returns the string with the roman number
    return romansArray.reverse().join("");
}

console.log(convertToRoman(1000));
```

You could shorten it a bit more with a diffrent object for look up and for building of `arr` and `romansArray`.

```js
function convertToRoman(num) {
    var arrConv = {
            0: { 1: 'I', 2: 'II', 3: 'III', 4: 'IV', 5: 'V', 6: 'VI', 7: 'VII', 8: 'VIII', 9: 'IX' },
            1: { 1: 'X', 2: 'XX', 3: 'XXX', 4: 'XL', 5: 'L', 6: 'LX', 7: 'LXX', 8: 'LXXX', 9: 'XC' },
            2: { 1: 'C', 2: 'CC', 3: 'CCC', 4: 'CD', 5: 'D', 6: 'DC', 7: 'DCC', 8: 'DCCC', 9: 'CM' },
            3: { 1: 'M', 2: 'MM', 3: 'MMM', 4: 'MMMM', 5: 'MMMMM', 6: 'MMMMMM', 7: 'MMMMMMM', 8: 'MMMMMMMM', 9: 'MMMMMMMMM' }
        },
        arr = num.toString().split("").reverse(),
        romansArray = arr.map(function (a, i) {
            return arrConv[i][a] || '';
        });

    return romansArray.reverse().join("");
}

console.log(convertToRoman(1234));
```

Comment: I think you need a little bit cleanup on `var arr = [num.length];
    arr = num.toString().split("").reverse();`

Answer (score 0):

One of The efficient Algorithm  for numbers till 3999.It works like a Mapping Table.

```
function convertToRoman(num) {
  var arr =[];
  var arr = num.toString().split('');
  var numarry =[];
  var count =0;

  for(var i = arr.length; i>0;i--){
    numarry.push(Number(arr[count])*Math.pow(10,i-1));
    ++count;
  }


var rom =[];
 debugger;
for(var i=0;i<numarry.length;i++)
{

  switch(numarry[i].toString().length){
      case 1:switch(numarry[i]){
        case 0 : rom.push( ''); continue;
        case 1 : rom.push( 'I'); continue;
        case 2 : rom.push( 'II'); continue;
        case 3 : rom.push( 'III'); continue;
        case 4 : rom.push( 'IV'); continue;
        case 5 : rom.push( 'V'); continue;
        case 6 : rom.push( 'VI');  continue;
        case 7 : rom.push( 'VII'); continue;
        case 8 : rom.push( 'VIII'); continue;
        case 9 : rom.push( 'IX'); continue;
        case 10 : rom.push( 'X');  continue; 
        default : rom.push( null);     continue; 
      }continue;
      case 2:switch(numarry[i]){
        case 0 : rom.push( ''); continue;
        case 10 : rom.push( 'X'); continue;
        case 20 : rom.push( 'XX'); continue;
        case 30 : rom.push( 'XXX'); continue;
        case 40 : rom.push( 'XL'); continue;
        case 50 : rom.push( 'L'); continue;
        case 60 : rom.push( 'LX');  continue;
        case 70 : rom.push( 'LXX'); continue;
        case 80 : rom.push( 'LXXX'); continue;
        case 90 : rom.push( 'XC'); continue;
        case 100 : rom.push( 'C'); continue;  
        default : rom.push( null); continue;    
      } continue;
      case 3:switch(numarry[i]){
        case 0 : rom.push( ''); continue;
        case 100 : rom.push( 'C'); continue;
        case 200 : rom.push( 'CC'); continue;
        case 300 : rom.push( 'CCC'); continue;
        case 400 : rom.push( 'CD'); continue;
        case 500 : rom.push( 'D'); continue;
        case 600 : rom.push( 'DC');  continue;
        case 700 : rom.push( 'DCC'); continue;
        case 800 : rom.push( 'DCCC'); continue;
        case 900 : rom.push( 'CM'); continue;
        case 1000 : rom.push( 'M');  continue; 
        default : rom.push( null);continue;      
      } continue;
      case 4:switch(numarry[i]){
        case 0 : rom.push( ''); 
        case 1000 : rom.push( 'M'); continue;
        case 2000 : rom.push( 'MM'); continue;
        case 3000 : rom.push( 'MMM'); continue;

        default : rom.push( null);      
      } continue;


  }


}
  return rom.join('') ;
}
convertToRoman(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's is my answer:

```
function convertToRoman(num) {

  var tempResult=[];
  var result=[];


    var romanNumbers={0:" ", 1: "I", 2: "II", 3:"III", 4:"IV", 5:"V",  6: "VI", 7:"VII", 8:"VIII", 9:"IX", 10:"X", 20:"XX", 30:"XXW", 40: "XL", 50:"L", 60:"LX", 70:"LXX", 80:"LXXX", 90:"XC", 100:"C", 400: "CD", 500: "D", 600:"DC", 700:"DCC", 800:"DCCC", 900:"CM", 1000: "M", 2000:"MM", 3000:"MMM" };

  var arr= num.toString().split("");


  for(var k=0; k< arr.length; k++){
    arr.splice(k,1, arr[k]*1);
  }

  var arrLength=arr.length;

  for(var k=arrLength-1; k>=0; k--){

    tempResult.push(romanNumbers[arr[k] * Math.pow(10, arrLength - (k+1)) ]);

  }


//   Getting rid of empty spaces
  for(var j=tempResult.length; j>=0; j--){
    if (tempResult[j]===" "){
      tempResult.splice(j, 1);
    }
  }
  result=tempResult.reverse().join("");

 return result;
}

convertToRoman(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

all of these answers rely on objects, which is bad becase objects don't have order

so use arrays to not mess up

```js
function romanize(num){
 if(!+num){
  return false;
 }
 var result = '';
 if(num < 0){
  num = Math.abs(num);
  result = '-';
 }
 var decimal = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];
 var roman = ["M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"];
 for(var i = 0; i <= decimal.length; i++){
  while(num % decimal[i] < num){
   result += roman[i];
   num -= decimal[i];
  }
 }
 return result;
}

console.log(romanize(9999));
console.log(romanize(1989));
```

it is also ***THE*** fastest

source: [selftaughtjs](https://www.selftaughtjs.com/algorithm-sundays-converting-roman-numerals/)

EDIT: at least i think objects have no order

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose we have an array and we have to convert array of numbers to roman, we can do it with below code I have written using recursion, easy and flexible solution, you can modify however you want on top of it.

```
let newArr = []
function romanizer(numbers) {
if(numbers.length === 0) return;
let numToBeUser = numbers;
const RomanNumerals = {
    1000: 'M', 900: 'CM', 500: 'D', 400: 'CD', 100: 'C', 90: 'XC', 50: 'L', 40: 'XL',
    1: 'I', 2:'II', 3: 'III', 4: 'IV', 5: 'V', 6: 'IV', 7: 'VII', 8: 'VIII', 9: 'IX', 10: 'X'
}
for(let i of Object.keys(RomanNumerals)) {
    let q = Math.floor(numbers[0]/RomanNumerals[i]);
        console.log(numbers[0], i)
       if(numbers[0] == i) {
           newArr.push(RomanNumerals[i])
       }
}
romanizer(numbers.slice(1))
return newArr;
}
```